# Removing element from Array is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove the first element from a `NSMutableArray` and Its not working

```
arrayforDistrits= [DistrictarrayForScroll removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

here "`DistrictarrayForScroll`" and "`arrayforDistrits`" are `NSMutableArray` and

it showing following error.Please check the image I have attached here.

[image]

Comment: can you please check whether array is NSMutableArray or only Array

Comment: @user2990885 What you expect from return array? Just edit your question, we will give correct answer for this?

Comment: your error is clearly telling you that `removeObjectAtIndex` returns void. It doesn't return an array with 1 less element, it removes it from the array its called on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should simply be:

```
[DistrictarrayForScroll removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

because removing an item from a mutable array does not return a new array.

If your intention is not to edit the original array but to create a new array without the item:

```
arrayforDistrits = [DistrictarrayForScroll mutableCopy];
[arrayforDistrits removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: u mean my code doesnt return new array is there any way to solve this?

Comment: you need to be clear what you're trying to do - i've edited based upon a guess...

Answer (score 4):

Because you are assigning `arrayForDistrits` but removeObjectAtIndex return void not any object.

For getting the object at 0 index you need to user

```
arrayForDistrits = [yourArray ojbectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCAFIH) apple's doc

return type of `removeObjectAtIndex:` is `void`. So You cann't assign it to `arrayforDistrits`.

Answer (score 3):

This method returns *void*:

```
@interface NSMutableArray : NSArray

- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```